# Synchronisation problems using QFieldSync

Tags: qgis, shapefile, database, geopackage, qfield

When resynchronizing data from QField GPKG project to QGis SHP project, using QFieldSync, attribute data are shifted to the right column. There is a lag, I have never seen something like that before.

Still, visualizing GPKG data using QGis Data Manager, without resynchronize, it can be seen that GPKG data are in compliance, it is found in the correct column.

QField GPKG Project screenshot
[image: QField GPKG Project screenshot]

QGis SHP Project screenshot (therefore after resynchronising)
[image: QGis SHP Project screenshote]

So, the issue comes from the resynchronising process using QFieldSync.

I don't really care but on-site coworkers that are not primarily directed at GIS will not understand it. Has anyone else come across a similar problem ?